# Decodificar en Prolog usando Peano

Tags: prolog

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de *Prolog* que trata de decodificar una lista.

```
decodifica([],[]).

decodifica([rlec(X,1)|L1],[X|L2]).
decodifica(L1,L2).

decodifica([rlec(X,N)|L1],[Xs|L1]):-
N1 is N-1, decodifica([rlec(X,N1)|L1],L2).

decodifica([E|L1],[E|L2]):- decodifica(L1,L2).
```

Un ejemplo es:

```
?- decodifica([b,rlec(a,3)],R).

R = [b, a, a, a] ;
```

Pero quiero usar notación *Peano*. ¿Alguna sugerencia?.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo la siguiente representación para los números de peano:

- `zero` para el número `0`.
- `succ(zero)` para el número `1`.
- ...
- `succ(N)` para `N+1`.

Simplemente tienes que cambiar tu caso base actual, `1`, por el primer número de peano, `zero`. Luego, en lugar de restar `1` a `N`, partes de un `succ(N)`, del cual vas quitando sucesores:

```
decodifica([],[]).

decodifica([rlec(X,zero)|L1],[X|L2]).
decodifica(L1,L2).

decodifica([rlec(X,succ(N))|L1],[Xs|L1]):-
decodifica([rlec(X,N)|L1],L2).

decodifica([E|L1],[E|L2]):- decodifica(L1,L2).
```